# What is an appropriate model for K continuous parameters on [0, 1]?

Tags: bayesian, interpretation, model, binary-data, joint-distribution

**Question Summary**

What kind of model is appropriate for estimating K parameters on [0, 1]? In particular, what kind of joint posterior should a model put on K parameters with support [0, 1]^K?

**Background/Motivation**

- I have K≈100 parameters a_k each continuous on [0, 1] which are known to me
- Each a_k represents an answer to a specific choice (binary question), where 0 means choosing option 0, 1 means choosing option 1, 0.5 means no preference, and all other values mean some degree of affinity for the closer option. It's like a survey where answers can be real.
- I will have a model M which estimates all K parameters (of course, the true values are not known to the model). M will estimate the parameters using outside information.
- I will want to use M to interpret the K choices. For example, if M overestimates a_3, a_22, and a_85 by similar amounts, this would suggest a relationship between choices 3, 22, and 85. If M can put a joint distribution on **a** then I can look for modes, conditional modes, etc.

**Question Details**

What framework would you choose for M? At one extreme, I could restrict M to the lattice points {0, 1}^K but that is obviously not very expressive.

Letting M be a real vector on [0, 1]^K is more expressive, but not enough: what about confidence? M should instead put a joint posterior distribution on the parameters with support [0, 1]^K. But what family of distributions is appropriate for this? Should it be parametric or non-parametric?

Once I have M, how do I extract patterns from the K choices? How do I use M to understand the relationships among the questions and between the questions and known answers? How do I use the known answers to better understand M?

**Research/thoughts so far**

- A beta distribution would have the right support and expressive power for a single parameter, but does not have multivariate support built in in any obvious way
- If M were simply a collection of K beta distributions, that would not clearly express relationships between the K choices. I could answer simple questions like which choices have similar distributions, or similar errors, but it still seems somehow not expressive enough.
- I looked up multivariate generalizations of the beta distribution, and found the Dirichlet. This is obviously too constrained since the sum of the variables equals 1.
- This seems related to a typical binary classification problem: M is a distribution relating a target real number `a` to some covariates **x**. However, that formulation differs from my actual problem in several ways:

  - the classification formulation doesn't model the joint distribution of the targets, or even use the fact that K is a known small constant
  - that formulation assumes known covariates, but in fact all I really have/care about is a distribution on the targets **a** and the relationship between this distribution and the true values.

Any help clearing up my thoughts is appreciated!